# Use the binomial theorem to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{c}$ converges to 1 for any c > 0.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I will start following an Analysis 1 course from next week on, and I'm reading into the subject a bit. There's an exercise in the book that I can't solve. A similar one follows that exercise and they seem pretty much related.

This is really more about the formal epsilon definition of convergence than that of limits. The chapter isn't on limits, but on convergence (although they are closely related).

Use the binomial theorem to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{c}$ converges to 1 for any c > 0.

and

Use the binomial theorem to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}$ converges to 1.

Note that this is the first ever chapter about series (and convergence) I've ever come across, and that it's therefore introductory. So there should be an 'easy' solution to the question.

EDIT: 
I've come as far as:
We want to prove there is an $n$* so that for any $n>=n$*, 
$|\sqrt[n]{c}-1|<\epsilon$ 
for any $\epsilon>0$.

Consider the case of c>1.
Then $|\sqrt[n]{c}-1|=\sqrt[n]{c}-1<\epsilon$

So
$\sqrt[n]{c}<\epsilon+1$
$c<(\epsilon+1)^n$

Now since $n\epsilon<(\epsilon+1)^n$ by the binomial theorem (I skip this proof for now), if 
$c<n\epsilon$ our statement still holds.
That is if

$n>c/\epsilon$
So consider the choice of $n$*$>c/\epsilon$.

Now this should be the so-called scratch-work. I don't know how to prove it, because inserting $n$* into the equation is gonna get really messy.

Also I wonder if I made no assumptions I shouldn't make, did no things that are plain wrong, or if I took a route that's way too hard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited my proof so it works with $\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I've noticed that you have changed your question to require "$\epsilon-\delta$" proof "from scratch". Just use the same inequalities proved below:

$1\le\sqrt[n]{c}\le 1+\frac{c}{n}$

$1\le\sqrt[n]{n}\le 1+\sqrt\frac{2}{n-1}$

Then for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ find $n_0$ and $n_1$ such as $\frac{c}{n}<\epsilon$ for $n>n_0$ and $\sqrt\frac{2}{n-1}<\epsilon$ for $n>n_1$

Then you will get

$|\sqrt[n]{c}-1|<\epsilon$ respectively $|\sqrt[n]{n}-1|<\epsilon$

OLD POST:

First part:

Write $\sqrt[n]{c}=1+b_n$, with $b_n>0$

Raise to the power $n$ and use Binomial Theorem:

$c=(1+b_n)^n=1+{n\choose 1}b_n+{n\choose 2}b_n^2+...+{n\choose n}b_n^n\ge {n\choose 1}b_n=nb_n$

since all the terms ${n\choose k}b_n^k$ on the right side are positive.

We get $n b_n\le c$ from where:

$0\le b_n\le\frac{c}{n}\rightarrow 0$

Second part:

Write $\sqrt[n]{n}=1+a_n$, with $a_n>0$

Raise to the power $n$ and use Binomial Theorem:

$n=(1+a_n)^n=1+{n\choose 1}a_n+{n\choose 2}a_n^2+...+{n\choose n}a_n^n\ge {n\choose 2}a_n^2$

since all the terms ${n\choose k}a_n^k$ on the right side are positive.

We get $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a_n^2\le n$ from where:

$0\le a_n\le\sqrt\frac{2}{n-1}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: I made some corrections to my post. Somehow mistakes keep creeping in. Though I trust you to double check and put the things together correctly.

Comment: That's all right, it's helped a lot anyways! Also for that second time you use the Binomial Theorem, shouldn't it be $<$ instead of $\le$, since there is a first term (for $k=1$) that is greater than 0, since $a_{n}>0$

Comment: Do you mean $<$ instead of $\le$?

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether it is $<$ of $\le$

Comment: Yeah I see it doesn't matter for the limit, but I'm just wondering as to whether it's a correct statement concerning the Bin. Theorem.

Comment: Can you indicate where exactly is your concern?

Comment: $n=(1+a_n)^n=1+{n\choose 1}a_n+{n\choose 2}a_n^2+...+{n\choose n}a_n^n\ge {n\choose 2}a_n^2$

I believe, that the $\ge$ sign should be a $>$ sign, right? Since for $n\ge2$ the first terms are both greater than 0.

Comment: Yes, you may safely put the stronger $>$ instead of my $\ge$. But it is not essential. You can also put $1<\sqrt[n]{c}<1+\frac{c}{n}$ if you want. But again, it does not matter.

Comment: Hey Momo, I found something interesting in my book. I made it to the next chapter in which the Squeeze/Sandwich theorem is introduced. Now one of the exercises is to do these two exercises again, and this time use the Sandwich theorem. Now this implies that we shouldn't have used it last time, and also that there is another solution where the Binomial Theorem isn't used. Now it's clear that $1\le\sqrt[n]{c}$, however how would the right hand side follow without the Bin. Theorem? And can we somehow wipe away our use of the Sandwich theorem in the above proof? I'd appreciate your help again.

Comment: The $\epsilon$ proof does not use the sandwich theorem. To use sandwich theorem you take the limit in the first two inequalities, without using $\epsilon$

Comment: Also, if you don't want to use Binomial theorem, you may prove using induction $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$ to use for the first inequality (a.k.a. Bernoulli's inequality), and $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$ to use for the second inequality. But unless it is required by your assignment, you should use Binomial theorem to shorten the proof.

Comment: All right, thanks a lot. I indeed misunderstood the meaning of the Sandwich theorem. Really thanks a lot for all your effort, and very clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$n=\left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^n
=\left(1+\left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)\right)^n
=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^k \geqslant\binom n2\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^2 \\\,\\ $$

Then  We have  $$n \ge \binom n2 (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^2  \iff1 \le\sqrt[n]{n} \le 1+ \sqrt{\frac 2{n-1}}$$
Now its time to use Sandwich Theorem to prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1 $

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So indeed since the limit of the right hand of the equation is 1 that tells us that our desired limit is indeed 1. I have 2 more questions though:

- Why did you, in particular, choose 2 as the specific value of k on the end of the first line?

-Is it possible to prove convergence using the definition that I have learned in my book? That is the definition where $|\sqrt[n]{n}-1|<\epsilon$ for any epsilon if we choose n to be greater than a specific n that may be dependent on epsilon?

Answer (score 0):

For any $\epsilon\ge0$, the first two terms of the Binomial Theorem say
$$
1+n\epsilon\le(1+\epsilon)^n\tag{1}
$$
Multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $\frac{(1-\epsilon)^n}{1+n\epsilon}$ and we get
$$
\begin{align}
(1-\epsilon)^n
&\le\frac{\left(1-\epsilon^2\right)^n}{1+n\epsilon}\\
&\le\frac1{1+n\epsilon}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
For $n\ge\frac{c+\frac1c}\epsilon$, we have
$$
1-\epsilon\le\left(\frac1{1+n\epsilon}\right)^{1/n}\le c^{1/n}\le(1+n\epsilon)^{1/n}\le1+\epsilon\tag{3}
$$
Taking the limit, we get
$$
1-\epsilon\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}c^{1/n}\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}c^{1/n}\le1+\epsilon\tag{4}
$$
Since $(4)$ holds for any $\epsilon\gt0$, we must have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}c^{1/n}=1\tag{5}
$$

---

**Extending the Result**

Since $1+x\le e^x$, we have that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le e$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}
&=\frac1n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\
&\le\frac en\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for $n\ge3$, we have that $n^{\large\frac1n}$ is a decreasing function, bounded below by $1$. This means that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{\large\frac1n}$ exists.

Since we have $(5)$, we can proceed as follows
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\large\frac1n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n)^{\large\frac1{2n}}\tag{7a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\large\frac1{2n}}\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\large\frac1{2n}}\tag{7b}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\large\frac1n}\tag{7c}\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{7d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(7a)}$: substitute $n\mapsto2n$
$\text{(7b)}$: product of limits is the limit of the products
$\text{(7c)}$: square $\text{(7b)}$ and divide by the left side of $\text{(7a)}$
$\text{(7d)}$: apply $(5)$